# Filter temperature effect using correlation coefficient

Tags: statistics, octave

I have

```
mat(2,n)=[temperature, length]
```

I know correlation coefficient

```
Corr=corr (mat(:,1), mat(:,2))=0.8
```

How do I filter effect of temperature on `length`. Should I simply multiply 'length' with (1-.8)?

I am using Octave.